# traversing through the linked list and returning the char* values

Tags: c

I am having problem returning char* values from the linked list can someone please please help
How can i return char* values within a while loop? When i try to run my program i get a single value from my linked list looping forever with the following code:

```
char * list_next(list *l)
{    
   list *currentPosition = NULL;    
   currentPosition = l->next; //skipping dummy value in the singly linked list

  while (currentPosition != NULL)
  {
    currentPosition = currentPosition->next;
    return currentPosition->charValue;

  }

   return NULL;
}
```

this is how i am calling the function:

```
char * item;
while(item = list_next(list))    
printf("%s ",item);
```

Comment: Reading your function makes me think that you might appreciate functional programming (where you can say something along the lines of 'get me the charValue of each item in this list').

Comment: Does each list entry hold a string?

Comment: yes each node has char* charValue

Answer (score 1):

it would be easier to do something like

```
list* current = list->next; //skip the dummy

while(current)
{
    printf("%s ", current->charValue);
    current = current->next;
}
```

But since you have to do it with a function and to do it in the format you've got you'd do something like the following:

```
char* list_next(list **l)
{    
  if (*l != NULL)
  {
    char* value = (*l)->charValue;
    *l = (*l)->next;
    return value;
  }

   return NULL;
}
```

and call it like so

```
list* temp_list = my_list->next; //skip the dummy

char * item;
while(item = list_next(&temp_list))    
    printf("%s ",item);
```

You can only return 1 value from a function. To make recurring calls to the function like you originally had in your while loop to move through the entire list you have to modify the input parameter so the next call in the while loop operates on the next element in the list. Notice the `**` in the function parameters.

Comment: that would be easier but i need to return a char*

Comment: Instead of `while (*l != NULL)` you could just as well use `if (*l != NULL)`; the return statement in the loop body causes your loop to never iterate more than once.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe whoops, meant for that to be an if.

Comment: it still doesnt work i get request for member 'charValue' in something not a struct or a union also get the same thing with 'next' my struct:    struct node{ char * charvalue; struct node *next;}; typedef struct node list; also is there a way to use a single pointer because each time i call the function it should update the current pointer and return the next node to what it returned previously

Comment: Try with the added () in my edit above to the function. You have to use a double pointer because you need to update the passed in parameter value to successfully iterate through the list. if you wanted to use a single pointer youd have to iterate to the next element in the while loop from the calling function like the first simple answer. in that case you function would be pointless

Answer (score 0):

You are returning in the middle of the loop, so you don't get a chance to process the other nodes.

You need to change something to process multiple characters.  You could collect them into an array, but that introduces the problem of needing to know in advance how many items are in the list.   You could process the items inline, as ThePosey suggests.

But if you want the function to be `list_next` and return one item each time, then you need to 'return' two things: the list value, and the list pointer.  One way would be to modify the function signature:  `char * list_next(list **l)`.  If you pass in a pointer to a pointer, the function can use it as an out parameter and set it to the next node.

Comment: how can i return more than 1 char* in the while loop?